# Correspondece between Git client and server versions

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm starting with Git, I already read the documentation about how to use it, just to test I create a simple repository using GitHub, everything is working good, but if I want to use my own server (not using GitHub), this is just curiosity, is there a table or list about the version correspondence between the Git client and server? in other words can I use an older server on a newer client or vice versa? I searched on several pages but I can't find this exact info, could anybody know the answer of this question?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `git` package is not separated into a "server" and a "client", you would run the same `git` on your remote machine as the local one. To answer your questions: Git is extremely backwards compatible, meaning you can run an old version on one machine and a new version on the other and should be able to push/pull without any issues!

Have fun, `git` is a wonderful tool.

Comment: Great answer, I thought that there were 2 different Git applications (a server and a client), but as you said, there's only one Git that can act as a client and also as a server, thanks.

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help. Please "accept" my response if your question was answered!

Comment: Do you mean a GIT server running the latest version is extremely backward compatible with an old GIT client, or a GIT client running the latest version is extremely backward compatible with an old GIT server?