# Using an older Git version to access a repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository

I just asked a question about Git ([Correspondece between Git client and server versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918684/correspondece-between-git-client-and-server-versions)) but another one just came to my mind, can I use an older Git version on GitHub? is there a list or table with this info out there?, I search on their web sites but I can't find this info.

Thank you all.

Comment: These links here should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676656/git-version-compatibility
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314668/git-repository-backwards-compatibility/1354102#1354102

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (as I explained in "[Git version compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676714/6309)" that [ForgetfulFellow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723707/forgetfulfellow) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919434/using-an-older-git-version-to-access-a-repository-on-github#comment33200230_21919434))

The only limitation is: if you are using https url, that means smart-http and you want to use a [git older than 1.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9243773/6309) to support pushing to a GitHub repo.